# Stimulsoft report designer - Count sub groups

Tags: stimulsoft

Using stimulsoft designer, I built a report which contains groups and sub groups.
[image]
Next to "NO of Days", how can I show total number of subgroups (not rows) within that group? and how can I use conditional if for that?
I tried all ways (Count, CountDistinct, cCount, colCount) with no hope.

For designer view, check below:
[image]

Comment: Can GroupLine be your answer?

Comment: @YasharAliabasi Nop !

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the CountDistinct with the Group Header as a first parameter. This should calculate count for these groups.